# How to direct attention to unanswered question, if I cannot comment?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, unanswered-questions

I'm wondering if there's any way on SO to get an asker that abandoned a question to direct their attention to it and select an answer.
This has happened on 3 cases for me (I've only answered 4 questions, so 75%) and I can't get the 50 rep needed, to post a comment. There are comments on the question, but this doesn't seem to bother the original asker anyway.
This is very frustrating and there should be a way to deal with this situation. I tried flagging for moderator attention, but moderator(s) claimed this does not need their attention. The answers were provided promptly as well, in the timeframe of 10 minutes from asking!
Relevant links:

- [Inserting multiple values into MySQL with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488822/inserting-multiple-values-into-mysql-with-php/15489069#15489069)
- [Using php to find any external devices plugged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246620/using-php-to-find-any-external-devices-plugged-in/20247007#20247007)
- [How to check for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247130/how-to-check-for-type/20247276#20247276)

I can't be the only one infuriated by this.

Comment: You have more than enough rep to comment (when I checked now) :)

Comment: Achievement unlocked!  :)

Comment: That is really cool, guys! Thanks, but I doubt it will solve the problem of abandoned questions. If you believe that this is still discuss-worthy and a non-duplicate, I won't close this question. If you believe otherwise, I'll close it I suppose.

Comment: It is frustrating, but that's the way it is. Sometimes there are posters which should know better, but if you check their profile, you can see that they ask lot of questions, but never accept them.

Comment: If in this case you said that the original poster didn't care about the other comments, how would one additional comment change anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't be posting such a comment anyway, even if you did have the reputation.  It would be rude and inappropriate of you to nag the author to accept an answer.  They can accept an answer if they want, and they have every right to choose not to if they don't want to.

The moderators were 100% correct that there is nothing that they should be doing in this case; an accepted answer is entirely up to the author to award.

They were already notified that an answer was posted, when it was first posted, so you already know that, if they're reading their notifications, they have seen the answer.  If they choose to acknowledge that answer as the one that solved their problem, great, if they don't, that is also their decision to make.

Had you posted comments simply telling the author to accept an answer, those comments would (or at least should) be deleted.

Comment: I agree that it's rude to nag users to accept an answer, but it seems to me that there are some users who literally do not know about the green check box.

Comment: I feel this removes some of the "rewarding feeling" from the community. I take the time to provide them with a complete answer, and they never return. I'm not happy with this, but I suppose I have to accept this is just the way things are.
Putting more thought into this, I realized another type of reward - knowledge from researching a topic interesting to me. This is actually the best reward available.

Comment: And there is a minimum amount of time that you have to wait before you can even accept an answer in the first place.  In come cases, that amount of time, is enough for the OP to forget about the answer and move onto other things

Comment: @SamIam So what?  They'll generally figure it out eventually.  And it's certainly not the case here.  If the OP has any accepted answer at all, then clearly they're familiar with the functionality.  Most of these comments *mean* "accept my answer" even if they say, "you know you can accept answers".

Comment: @LauriPiisang If that is the sole reason that you're here, then that's an indication of a problem.  Most people are here because they enjoy answering questions, helping people, to learn from the process of teaching, etc.  The gamification should be just a little bit of extra encouragement; if it's your sole encouragement the quality of your contributions is likely to suffer.

Comment: @Servy : Putting more thought into this, I realized another type of reward - knowledge from researching a topic interesting to me. This is actually the best reward available.

Answer (score 3):

Having once been a new user, I can sympathize with your frustration in trying to earn enough reputation to do various things. However, this does not mean moderators should be prodding people to accept answers. Sometimes I accept answer right away because it answers my question. Other times I feel several of the answers are inadequate, or I'd like to wait until the answer gets enough votes that I feel confident there isn't another better answer that hasn't bubbled up yet.

Rather than getting mad, work on gaining reputation in other ways. You may wish to see the [FAQ on how to gain reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). Answer more questions. Ask questions. Accept answers to your questions. Suggest useful edits to other questions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the only real answer is to basically mind your own business. Ask questions when you have them. Answer when you can. Spend less time (and energy) getting frustrated (much less infuriated) about how others behave.